# Show clrcle overlay instead of marker in google map?

Tags: google-maps

I'm using gmap module on Drupal 6. I create a view and select gmap as style for my display.
Everything works fine but the map shows a Marker and I need to show a circle overlay instead of the marker so that the map hide the exact address location.

I tried all setting within gmap module but...nope.

Where is the right place for this setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view settings should allow you to choose the marker style. Don't have the module installed to check but [a comment on the "Provide Gmap marker field for use in Views listing" feature request](http://drupal.org/node/371597#comment-1253391) illustrates how I remember it:

> Under style: GMap in your view try clicking on the setting icon next
>   to where it says GMap. An option box should appear below the view with
>   some options:
>
> - Marker handling: By content type (for node views)
> - By term (for node views)
> - Use single marker type

Comment: I tried all option in my display view but I can't figure out how to get it.